# jQuery Dependencies?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a jquery function that takes an element: `<div id="hello"></div>` and maninpulates the DOM and appends lots of new elements onto it, e.g.

```
<div id="hello"></div>
```

*run jquery function*

```
<div id="hello"><div id="a"></div><div id="b"></div></div>
```

Ive encountered the problem that trying to select `$('#a')` or `$('#b')` on 'document.ready' returns 0 items as the first function obviously hasnt finished yet.

What are my options?

I've tried using `$.live()` to some success.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? `live()` and `delegate()` are used for event registration, but it may be that you need to ensure that the order of execution is correct rather than find out how to operate on DOM elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 'delegate' is the preferred method for binding events to dynamically created elements. See the documentation for reasons why.

> http://api.jquery.com/delegate/